# How to request permissions in a Flutter plugin?

Tags: android, permissions, flutter

I am trying to use a simple Flutter plugin (speech recognition wrapper) and have no idea how to request the appropriate permissions on Android 23 or newer. In the Dart part I have:

```
  Future requestPermissions() => 
  _channel.invokeMethod("speech.requestPermissions");
```

In the Android part:

```
  public class SpeechRecognitionPlugin implements MethodCallHandler, RecognitionListener,
    PluginRegistry.RequestPermissionResultListener {
```

Plugin registration:

```
  public static void registerWith(Registrar registrar) {
    final MethodChannel channel = new MethodChannel(registrar.messenger(), "speech_recognition");
    SpeechRecognitionPlugin speechRecognitionPlugin = new 
    SpeechRecognitionPlugin(registrar.activity(), channel);
    channel.setMethodCallHandler(speechRecognitionPlugin);
    registrar.addRequestPermissionResultListener(speechRecognitionPlugin);
  }
```

Method call:

```
else if (call.method.equals("speech.requestPermissions")) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "speech.requestPermissions");
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(activity,
                Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO)) {
            Toast.makeText(activity.getApplicationContext(), "This application needs the Record Audio permission for recognition to work", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Requesting permissions");
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO},
                    1);
        }
        result.success(hasRecordAudioPermission());
```

Result callback:

```
@Override                                                                                            
public boolean onRequestPermissionResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    boolean granted = false;
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 1: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                granted = true;
            }
            speechChannel.invokeMethod("speech.onPermission", granted);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

From logcat I see that the "speech.requestPermissions" call happens, but standard Android system permission request is not shown, just this in the logcat may be related:

```
D/ViewRootImpl(21171): #1 mView = android.widget.LinearLayout{64f050b 
V.E...... ......I. 0,0-0,0 #102039d android:id/toast_layout_root}
D/ViewRootImpl(21171): MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) or=1
D/ViewRootImpl(21171): #3 mView = null
```

What is the correct way to request permissions for Flutter plugins?

**EDIT**: This does not apply to the first run, when the dialog shows correctly, but to subsequent runs when the user did not grant the permission at first or revoked it via settings. I realize that changes the question significantly (making it appear as edge case), but Android permissions are not supposed to work that way.

**EDIT**: The permissions are present in AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 5):

Use [Permission plugin for flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/permissions_plugin)

Request permission

```dart
import 'package:permissions_plugin/permissions_plugin.dart';

Map<Permission, PermissionState> permission = await PermissionsPlugin
    .requestPermissions([
        Permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
        Permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
        Permission.READ_PHONE_STATE
    ]);
```

Check status permission

```dart
import 'package:permissions_plugin/permissions_plugin.dart';

Map<Permission, PermissionState> permission = await PermissionsPlugin
    .checkPermissions([
      Permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
      Permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
      Permission.READ_PHONE_STATE
    ]);
```

Comment: In this package is mentioned, that it only for now supports just android.

Answer (score 0):

I have this working for location permissions. The only thing I'm doing differently is in your method call here:

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO},
                1);
```

Instead of using 'ActivityCompat' I store the registrar in a local final variable and I'm doing the following :

```
registrar.activity().requestPermissions(activity,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO},
                1);
```

EDIT: Also make sure that you have included the relevant permissions in your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- Add this -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />

    <!-- Flutter stuff --->
</manifest>
```

Comment: Thanks for assuring that this is at least a way to go. I have edited the question, first run works, but requesting permissions on the fly does not. Sorry for not mentioning it before.

Comment: You will have to add the permission to the manifest as well (if you haven't already done that). See my edited answer for an example

Comment: How are you checking to see if the permission has or hasn't already been granted? I'm using this in my plugin: 
PermissionChecker.checkSelfPermission(registrar.activity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED

Comment: int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO);
return (permissionCheck == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED); I will try your version when I get to the code.

Comment: Unfortunately, no change. Now that I think about it, I do not know what did I expect from this change, the permission request call is no different.

Comment: Is there any way you could post a more complete version of your code?

Comment: The code I am tinkering with is on github, I have just forked it and commited my changes: https://github.com/comodoro/speech_recognition

Comment: In the branch that you linked the required permissions are not listed in the AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Indeed, relevant notion. I have always assumed permissions had to be in the app manifest (not the plugin itself), nevertheless this should be tried. It has been, still no change

Answer (score -1):

Let's say you want to request camera permission using [`permission_handler`](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler) package.

1. In `pubspec.yaml` file:

   ```
   permission_handler: ^8.0.0+2
   ```
2. (For Android) Add the permission to `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` file

   ```
   <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/> 
     ...
    </manifest>
   ```
3. (For iOS),

   (i) Add this to your `info.plist` file

   ```
   <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
   <string>App needs camera permission to work</string>
   ```

   (ii) Add `'PERMISSION_CAMERA=1'` to your `Podfile`.

   ```
   post_install do |installer|
     installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
       flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)

       target.build_configurations.each do |config|
         config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] ||= [
           '$(inherited)',

           ## Add the following line.
            'PERMISSION_CAMERA=1'
         ]

       end
     end
   end
   ```
4. Request the permission:

   ```dart
   final status = await Permission.camera.request();
   if (status == PermissionStatus.granted) {
     print('Permission granted');
   } else if (status == PermissionStatus.denied) {
     print('Permission denied. Show a dialog and again ask for the permission');
   } else if (status == PermissionStatus.permanentlyDenied) {
     print('Take the user to the settings page.');
     await openAppSettings();
   }
   ```